# Process x509 client certificates in Perl

Tags: perl, x509

I am working with [`Web::ID`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::ID) and have some questions.

From the [FAQ for Web::ID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::ID::FAQ#How-can-I-use-WebID-in-Perl):

> ### How can I use WebID in Perl?
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, you need to use [`Web::ID`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::ID) directly. Assuming you've configured your web server to request a client certificate from the browser, and you've managed to get that client certificate into Perl in PEM format, then it's just:
>
> `my $webid  = Web::ID->new(certificate => $pem);`
>
> `my $uri    = $webid->uri;`
>
> And you have the URI.

Anyway I'm stuck at the `.. get that client certificate into Perl ..`  part.

I can see the client certificate is being passed along to the script by examining the `%ENV`environment variable. But I am still unsure how to actually process it in the way that `Web::ID` does... like examine the SAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) you will find the PEM encoded client certificate in the environment variable `SSL_CLIENT_CERT`, so all you need is to call

```
 my $webid  = Web::ID->new(certificate => $ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT});
```

However, Apache **does not set the `SSL_CLIENT_CERT` environment variable by default**. This is for performance reasons - setting a whole bunch of environment variables before spawning your Perl script (via mod_perl, or CGI, or whatever) is wasteful if your Perl script doesn't use them, so it only sets a small set of environment variables by default. You need to [configure Apache correctly](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions) to tell it you want ALL DA STUFFZ. In particular you want something like this in .htaccess, or your virtual host config, or server config file:

```
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
```

While you're at it, you also want to make sure Apache is configured to ask clients to present a certificate. For that you want something like:

```
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
```

All this is [kind of covered in the documentation for Web::ID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::Auth::WebID#Apache2-mod_perl-and-CGI) but not especially thoroughly.

Comment: HA! I knew it was that.

`my $webid  = Web::ID->new(certificate => $ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT});` you are the man tobyink i love you!

For the record I had read everything but was overthinking things. That single line of code solved SO MUCH, i wish that line was in the documentation lol