# Process x509 client certificates in Perl (further processing)

Tags: perl, x509

This question is an extension of [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658650/process-x509-client-certificates-in-perl).

Basically the last question asked how to get the cert into perl and ive done that with the `Web::ID` package..

`my $webid  = Web::ID->new(certificate => $ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT});`

I verified this works by calling `blessed($webid)` and also `Dumper($webid)`

however I still cant call `$webid->uri` which is an attribute that should have been set up for me. In fact I cant call any attribute other than `$webid->certificate`

So basically im still unable to parse the SAN.

**EDIT**

So now directly using the `Web::ID::Certificate` package i can directly loop through the SAN array.

`my $cert = Web::ID::Certificate->new(pem => $ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT});
foreach (@{ $cert->subject_alt_names }) {
   print "SAN: ", $_->type, " = ", $_->value;
}`

So my question is answered.. but... Im still confused...
I guess I dont understand why the `Web::ID`'s `uri` isnt being set?

Why are none of my  `$webid`'s attributes being set?

**EDIT2** at tobyink's request:

`$VAR1 = bless( { 'certificate' => bless( { 'pem' => '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDlzCCAn+gAwIBAgIJAI6PdfUNmz5oMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEgxCzAJBgNV BAYTAlhYMREwDwYDVQQHDAhJbnRlcm5ldDEQMA4GA1UECgwHQml0bWFyazEUMBIG A1UEAwwLbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwIBcNMTQxMDMxMTI1NjAzWhgPMjExNDEwMDcxMjU2 MDNaMEgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlhYMREwDwYDVQQHDAhJbnRlcm5ldDEQMA4GA1UECgwH Qml0bWFyazEUMBIGA1UEAwwLbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCna/Lvihx5nD3LbjfLo0vDIQkkSR6u/bKbwm346VJBVRh6 /K5gHM19os7ZeNp8GlArl0OGtF5QSf+TGHt0hD8RtgACJumdn/oATYGvGfdwnLu0 vUD9XHc6wzl+thvp7cT1Dw8BtEvUi+e4UBpIJMXCJkMt+Er23Mn288EbSGsC8q1u ga6Vp4toX4/fSuDEHAlEGeVhWCJfHy26lpaHPPuLTUfr1/8b1TiYI19rit4HK/wS MfKfXkLXc2a+Clr+/girqa60Q9zXP0GjQRawZ/B8WHVKBkE3DqOp/jEtEytS7Ojv 2ieylYT+/IhiQgqVS6CgE6vZ65PRzuQOItFoNaV7AgMBAAGjgYEwfzAvBgNVHREE KDAmhhVodHRwOi8vbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQvI2mBDTFAbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwHQYDVR0O BBYEFIBUZ3r+B/dc900RyvhlVXq4Znf9MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFIBUZ3r+B/dc900R yvhlVXq4Znf9MAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAE/adF6C MJHoh1IxnwrvPLZ0S66XD0xPHlQ6ZKvuKqTX2nakf7vXaSzFCkoXJ6Vbv19NXpqZ 28jRBCgv0rszT8ODICApp65XsFc67w5S2/+soIDKs3ZLuKBPvRu6x7cPIeSDfj2J w6fQ9dXOSzUmdPCoorudrW+L/CmKI8Tn2I2KQah6p9HGh0/XnxXob0kGkGeJF5sR WOLQOUT+HpEjAy3Eeu1nygxqscaTESKv+0hLV7yHHzJl9TJRFbNw4zYzU3h8t8M+ pSu3SD4YC3HixmZarz7fV36zWaAxJBHRtBkbOwgOMBY4wzfpMPPV4fQ61Qio8DLR lN7nzvuQD+BA4OQ= -----END CERTIFICATE----- ' }, 'Web::ID::Certificate' ) }, 'Web::ID' );`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the certificate is correctly set up for [WebID](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/webid/spec/tls/)? Not all x509 certificates are. If you post the PEM file, I'd be happy to check. (Remember this is just the public part of the key, so there shouldn't be any security issue posting it publicly.)

Comment: Yes it's correct I can log into a freinds site using the webid. I also checked it at -> https://auth.my-profile.eu/auth/index.php?verbose=on

Comment: after successfully creating the reference `$webid` any call to any of its attribute other than `certificate` makes the script crash.

Comment: When i checked your example data with ``openssl x509 -in certfile.txt -noout`` it gave me an error ``PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode``

Comment: @vorsprung strange.. i dont get that.. are you sure you copy pasted it correctly without some space messing up the encoding??

Comment: http://leathan.net/ returns RDFa. Do you have an RDFa parser installed? (i.e. RDF::RDFa::Parser)

Comment: I do now, to be clear the SAN in that cert is `http://leathan.net/#i` and i can use it to log in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. I've written this little script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::ID;

printf "%s: %s\n", $_, $_->VERSION for qw(
    Web::ID
    Crypt::X509
    RDF::RDFa::Parser
    RDF::Trine
    RDF::Query
);

print Web::ID->new(certificate => <<'END')->uri, "\n";

    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIDlzCCAn+gAwIBAgIJAI6PdfUNmz5oMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEgxCzAJBgNV
    BAYTAlhYMREwDwYDVQQHDAhJbnRlcm5ldDEQMA4GA1UECgwHQml0bWFyazEUMBIG
    A1UEAwwLbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwIBcNMTQxMDMxMTI1NjAzWhgPMjExNDEwMDcxMjU2
    MDNaMEgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlhYMREwDwYDVQQHDAhJbnRlcm5ldDEQMA4GA1UECgwH
    Qml0bWFyazEUMBIGA1UEAwwLbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA
    A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCna/Lvihx5nD3LbjfLo0vDIQkkSR6u/bKbwm346VJBVRh6
    /K5gHM19os7ZeNp8GlArl0OGtF5QSf+TGHt0hD8RtgACJumdn/oATYGvGfdwnLu0
    vUD9XHc6wzl+thvp7cT1Dw8BtEvUi+e4UBpIJMXCJkMt+Er23Mn288EbSGsC8q1u
    ga6Vp4toX4/fSuDEHAlEGeVhWCJfHy26lpaHPPuLTUfr1/8b1TiYI19rit4HK/wS
    MfKfXkLXc2a+Clr+/girqa60Q9zXP0GjQRawZ/B8WHVKBkE3DqOp/jEtEytS7Ojv
    2ieylYT+/IhiQgqVS6CgE6vZ65PRzuQOItFoNaV7AgMBAAGjgYEwfzAvBgNVHREE
    KDAmhhVodHRwOi8vbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQvI2mBDTFAbGVhdGhhbi5uZXQwHQYDVR0O
    BBYEFIBUZ3r+B/dc900RyvhlVXq4Znf9MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFIBUZ3r+B/dc900R
    yvhlVXq4Znf9MAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAE/adF6C
    MJHoh1IxnwrvPLZ0S66XD0xPHlQ6ZKvuKqTX2nakf7vXaSzFCkoXJ6Vbv19NXpqZ
    28jRBCgv0rszT8ODICApp65XsFc67w5S2/+soIDKs3ZLuKBPvRu6x7cPIeSDfj2J
    w6fQ9dXOSzUmdPCoorudrW+L/CmKI8Tn2I2KQah6p9HGh0/XnxXob0kGkGeJF5sR
    WOLQOUT+HpEjAy3Eeu1nygxqscaTESKv+0hLV7yHHzJl9TJRFbNw4zYzU3h8t8M+
    pSu3SD4YC3HixmZarz7fV36zWaAxJBHRtBkbOwgOMBY4wzfpMPPV4fQ61Qio8DLR
    lN7nzvuQD+BA4OQ=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----

END
```

It produces the following output:

```
Web::ID: 1.927
Crypt::X509: 0.51
RDF::RDFa::Parser: 1.097
RDF::Trine: 1.010
RDF::Query: 2.912
http://leathan.net/#i
```

If you've got up-to-date versions of these modules, then you *should* be fine.

Comment: really thank you for your time. It all works now, including the code in the original question (i.e. `$webid->uri`)

I think it was because I didnt have the `RDF::` packages installed or at the correct version?? It seems strange to me... but it worked after installing that, anyway thanks.. and cool coding style :P

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem was not having "RDF::RDFa::Parser" installed.

`cpan install RDF::RDFa::Parser` solved my problem.